# What need is there for the English language to include both "affect" and "effect"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, homophones

I do not know the history of the words *affect* and *effect.* I know their use in English, with the words being verbs and nouns respectively, but as a point of curiosity and enthusiasm, I wonder if there is a need to have separate words at all? Is there ever a case where there is a sentence that would be ambiguous if the wrong word was used? For example, consider the following sentences:

> I am happy for you too.
>
> I am happy for you two.

(I believe a comma might be needed in the first sentence, but bear with me)

These sentences have different meanings. The first states that the speaker is happy for the listen *as well*. The second states that the reader is happy for the listener and another individual. It is important, then for English to have different words for these two meanings. Considering *affect* and *effect*, is there ever a case where we could have an ambiguous sentence like this? Or could we instead drop either *affect* or *effect* and use the remaining word exclusively?

As an aside:
I understand that English is a language birthed from many other languages, and as a result contains many duplicates of words. For example (this is my understanding), *cow* and *beef* were at one point essentially the same, but the words are rooted from the languages that were used by those who raised the cattle (Germanic, *cow*) and those who consumed the meat (French, *beef*).

Comment: You haven't covered *all* the different meanings. Even forgetting about homophonous ***two***, in normal conversational contexts, *I am happy for you too* could mean *I **too** am happy for you* - ***I am another one** [of those people who are happy for you]*, as opposed to ***You are another one** [of those people who I am happy for].*

Comment: One fundamental problem with this type of question is they fail to consider: *who* do you imagine would do the "dropping" of the word? There is no Academy of the English Language. There is no single "official" dictionary. How do you get a directive out to 1.5 billion people "Okay, everyone, it's no longer affect and effect, just use effect"?

Comment: Because ***affect / effect*** are often indistinguishable in speech, there's potential ambiguity in, for example, *He cannot **affect / effect** the plan*. Where ***affect*** would mean he's unable to ***alter*** the plan, but (uncommon, but grammatically fine) ***effect*** would mean he's unable to ***implement*** the plan.

Comment: @MarkBeadles, I stated in my post that this was a question of curiosity. Do you really think anyone would consider that the language could actually be changed?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your first comment is a little frustrating because it appears as though you did not finish and understand my question before responding. Your second comment is helpful though. Perhaps repost it as an answer?

Comment: Reubens4Dinner: I'm one of millions of Anglophones who *usually* stick with ***who*** for all contexts, rather than getting bogged down with ***whom***. But there's always the slight risk that someone (some *idiot*, imho! :) might think I'm poorly educated. On the other hand, I would never choose incorrectly between ***affect*** and ***effect*** unless it was an unnoticed "slip of the pen".

Comment: Alas, there is a long history of people trying to change languages to suit their own agendas... However, my main point is that language does not evolve through explicit decisions made by consideration of things like efficiency and redundancy. The situation with "affect" and "effect" - two words with very close meanings and very close pronunciations - came to be through the accidents of history.

Comment: I can't answer your question, because I don't really understand what you're asking. There's *potential* ambiguity in the ***spoken*** example I gave, but that doesn't exist in the ***written*** version. And ambiguity can involve different possible meanings of the ***same*** word, as well as different words themselves (homophones). I don't know what you're focusing on, if anything.

Comment: I am focused on if there are instances of ambiguity among the use of *affect* and *effect* in written language.

Comment: Note: _veal_ and _beef_ were never the same, just as _cow/ox_ and _calf_ were never the same. They are both Norman French words, referring to different animals (well, the same animal, but at different stages in life). You’re thinking rather of the pairs _cow/ox_ ~ _beef_, and _calf_ ~ _veal_, respectively. Those are indeed doublets.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Perhaps I'm being fanciful, but I still believe that the reason we use ***beef*** for the meat we eat, and ***cow*** for the animal we "husband" is because as servants to our Norman overlords (who always said ***beouf***) we got used to *them* telling us what they wanted us to serve for dinner (which they obviously wanted ***cooked***).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, FumbleFingers comment is a better version of what I was (poorly) trying to say.

Comment: I was half expecting some native Francophone to comment *Ca c'est **vachement** fou, FF!*

Comment: It might happen yet!

Comment: @Reubens Yes, I understood what you were alluding to – you just accidentally picked two different French words instead of one English, one French. I’ve gone ahead and fixed it for clarity. :-)

Comment: 'This effected the process' and 'this affected the process' have very different meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there ever a case where there is a sentence that would be ambiguous if the wrong word was used?

Yes.

Both words can be verbs*: "I want to affect/effect change."

Both words can be nouns*: "The affect/effect is pronounced."

> is [there] a need to have separate words at all?

Probably not. English is full of homonyms and in some cases multiple meanings are grammatical.

*I addressed the letter* -> Did I put an address on it, or did I give attention to its contents?

*The bat flew out of his hands* -> A baseball bat, or an animal?

*A huge crane fell into the water* -> The bird, or the machine?

If we're able to deal with these ambiguities, we could probably live with a single spelling for *affect/effect*.

---

* The verbal form of *effect* is less common than the nominal, and the nominal form of *affect* is even less common, but they do, or did, exist.

Comment: Thank you for providing a helpful and unpatronizing answer!

Comment: The full OED has about a dozen different definitions for ***affect*** as a noun. All are flagged ***obsolete*** except I-5-b (marked as *specific* to Psychology and Psychiatry) *A feeling or subjective experience accompanying a thought or action or occurring in response to a stimulus*. And to be honest, until I just consulted the OED, I didn't know that even *that* one was still considered "current". For almost all people who even know there are two words/spellings, the difference is a matter of verb and noun usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've added a note to this effect.  But I'm comfortable with that part of the answer being technically, if not practically correct, since the conclusion is that the ambiguity doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: I don't see the sentence being ambiguous on its own if the wrong word was used. To me, ambiguity suggests that the sentence could mean two or more things in its current form, and which thing it means is difficult to tell. I see the sentence *meaning something different* if the wrong word is used: "The affect is pronounced" means that the elicited emotional response is pronounced; "the effect is pronounced" means that *whatever is brought about by the cause* is pronounced. The only ambiguity would be in a situation where the context suggested that the main meaning was improbable.

Comment: ...-do- exist. All four affect/effect x noun/verb are in current usage. Yes, the affect-noun and effect-verb aren't the primary ones by a long shot but are definitely quite current in use.

Comment: Answers are considered good on ELU when they contain reasonable supporting evidence. Without  FumbleFingers' added research, this answer could mislead someone into thinking that 'affect' is used as a noun just as often as 'effect', and that 'The affect is pronounced' is a commonly encountered sentence.

Comment: AFFECT usually functions as a verb. E.g. Your curse won't affect me. EFFECT is the result of AFFECT. Your curse didn't have any EFFECT on me.  It has other extended meanings, these are the common ones.